# How to retrieve hits and aggregations using ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch API we can retrieve at once `hits` and `aggregations`

```
{
    "query": { "match_all": {} },
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations" : {
        "category" : {
            "terms": { "field": "category" }
        }
    }
}
```

But in the `ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate` class the `search` and `aggregations` a 2 different methods.

Is it possible to run both at the same time and to retrieve the results for both?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible, there's an [issue in Jira for this request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-796)